# How to keep MutationObserver triggering when html is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I've an ordered list that the user can edit. I'm adding on additional html code to each list element entry.
I'm using the MutationObserver for this.
This works fine when I have one list. However, if I dynamically create a heading and restart a new list the MutationObserver no longer fires.

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnt6dqmv/12/) for demo of this. 
Create new list elements and additional html is appended to each element when enter is pressed. Add in text for a heading and select the "Make Heading" button. First list is closed, heading is created and new list is started. However, no html is appended for any new list elements in either list.

I have tried disconnecting the observer and reconnecting but this does not work.

```html
<div><button id="makeHeading">Make Heading</button></div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <ol contenteditable=true class="editor">
    <li><br></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

```js
function subscriber(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
      const prev = node.previousSibling;
      if (prev && prev.innerHTML !== undefined && prev.tagName === 'LI') {
        prev.innerHTML = prev.innerHTML + "- (additional html)";
      }
    });
  });
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(subscriber);
observer.observe(document.querySelector('ol[contenteditable]'), {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

document.getElementById('makeHeading').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.baseNode.parentElement.tagName === 'LI') {

    // dirty way to get DIV for example
    var parent = selection.baseNode.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    var liContent = selection.baseNode.parentElement;
    parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML + "<div class='heading'>" + liContent.innerText + "</div><ol contenteditable=true class='editor'><li><br></li></ol>";

    // observer.disconnect();
    // observer.observe(document.querySelector('ol[contenteditable]'), { childList: true, subtree: true });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: I'd suggest not using a MutationObserver for this. It's generally considered to be a 'last resort' technique when there's no better option. In this case I would look in to either raising an event to add the other required HTML, or simply adding it in the main `click` event handler. I can't really see the purpose of adding HTML in the the external logic.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I already tried doing this on the 'enter' event. However, when I update the innerHtml I get odd results such as a preceding  empty list element. I may have been doing something wrong. do you have an example of how this could be done for updating a list element?

Comment: By assigning or appending to innerHTML you're effectively **destroying** everything inside, then it gets recreated anew with no event listeners or observers attached. Use the safe and more performant methods of modifying DOM: insertAdjacentHTML, insertAdjacentElement, createElement, appendChild, and so on.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for this. Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. I've substituted createElement, appendChild etc for the html string and innerHtml but the observer is still not triggering.

Comment: I don't have any reason to believe you did it right this time :-) unless I see the code.